# Order platform/CMS (private)

Tags: cms

A client of mine is selling en-gross products. He has a loyal client base that constantly requests orders via either rudimentary SMS/Phone, WhatsApp, Email.

My goal is to concentrate all the orders in a simple online platform, where he gives access to the clients and they place the order.

Thinking about building the solution from scratch although it's worth asking here if there are any solutions pre-built. The reason I'm not opting for Wordpress+WooCommerce is that the order is for private clients (which could be bypassed) and it doesn't require any payment up front.

Any light-weight CMS or framework out there?

Thanks!

Comment: No, with WooCommerce, you can create a group of users under the same role and have WooCommerce only sell products to a particular role. You can also require payment up front, that's kind of important with an online ordering.